# Approximation to $1.05^{1.02}$ with Taylor's Theorem $T_2f(a;(x,y))$ in the point $a = (1,1)$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

Let $f : (0, \infty)^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) := x^y$.

How can one find out an approximation to $1.05^{1.02}$ with Taylor's Theorem, i.e. $T_2f(a;(x,y))$ in the point $a = (1,1)$.

And how can one calculate, that the absolute error of the approximation above is smaller than $7 \cdot 10^{-5}$?

For the first question I thought about using the "Symmetry of second derivatives". Apparently we are allowed to use the following theorem:

Let $D \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and  $f \in C^k (D;\mathbb{R})$.

Further, let $i_1,..,i_k \in \text{{1,...n}}$.

Then we get

$$\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x_{ik} \cdot \cdot \cdot \partial x_{i1}}(x)  = \frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x_{\sigma(ik)} \cdot \cdot \cdot \partial x_{\sigma (i1)}} (x) $$

for all $x \in D$ and every permutation $\sigma:$ {$i_1,...,i_k$} $\to$ {$i_1,...,i_k$}.

I don't know how to continue though..

Comment: I believe you are a bit over-complicating a simple matter:

$$ 1.05^{1.02} = \frac{21}{20}\exp\left[\frac{2}{100}\log\left(1+\frac{5}{100}\right)\right]$$
and we may use the Maclaurin series of $\exp(x)$ and $\log(1+x)$, namely $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$ and $x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$, to get that the RHS is approximately
$$ \frac{21}{20}\exp\left[\frac{1}{50}\left(\frac{5}{100}-\frac{25}{20000}\right)\right]=\frac{21}{20}\exp\left[\frac{39}{40000}\right]\approx \frac{21}{20}\left(1+\frac{39}{40000}+\frac{39^2}{2\cdot 40000^2}\right) $$

Comment: or $\color{green}{1.05102}\color{red}{4249\ldots}$

Comment: Even simpler: $$ \frac{21}{20}\sqrt[50]{1+\frac{1}{20}}\approx \frac{21}{20}\left(1+\frac{1}{20\cdot 50}-\frac{49}{20^2\cdot 5000}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks it really helped me. I also figured how to do it with Taylor. But how do you prove that your approximation is correct?